# How to align sublists and lists using enumitem correctly?

Tags: latex, alignment

I'm trying to configure aligning of lists and sublists using `enumitem`. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Lists:

\begin{itemize}[align=left, labelindent=0em, leftmargin=0em, itemindent=!, nosep, noitemsep]
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  %
  \begin{itemize}[nosep, noitemsep]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \end{itemize}
  %
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Labels are placed correctly, but the 1st lvl text start (1 and 5 lines) should align according to the 2nd lvl label (3 line), and the 2nd lvl text continuation (4 line) should align according to the 2nd lvl label (3 line) too. How can I achieve that? I tried to read https://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf, but it's all Greek to me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Only 3 arrows on the screen should be changed, 2nd, 3rd and 6th lines are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the code below work for you?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\setlist[itemize]{
  nosep,
  align=left,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  labelwidth=1.25em,
  itemindent=1.25em,
  labelsep=0pt,
}
\setlist*[itemize,2]{
  leftmargin=1.25em,
}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Lists:

\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  % 
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \end{itemize}
  % 
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

here's the screnshot:

[image]

---

EDIT. Use `\setlist` to make global settings and then its starred version to add adjustment per list, level of a specific list, etc. If it's a local for one list, you could even create a new list `\newlist` for a specific purpose (more in [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) documentation).